# Everytime i am trying to import an image using Scikit-image i am getting an error

Tags: image, import, python-3.6

```
import skimage
from skimage import data
camera=data.camera()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    camera=data.camera()
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\skimage\data\__init__.py", line 109, in camera
    return _load("camera.png")
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\skimage\data\__init__.py", line 96, in _load
    return imread(_os.path.join(data_dir, f), plugin='pil', as_gray=as_gray)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_io.py", line 48, in imread
    img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\manage_plugins.py", line 210, in call_plugin
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_plugins\pil_plugin.py", line 36, in imread
    return pil_to_ndarray(im, dtype=dtype, img_num=img_num)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_plugins\pil_plugin.py", line 66, in pil_to_ndarray
    image.seek(i)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 739, in seek
    if not self._seek_check(frame):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 306, in _seek_check
    return self.tell() != frame
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 827, in tell
    return self.__frame
AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute '_PngImageFile__frame'
```

Comment: Could you please add more context including a code snippet so that we know what is causing this error?

Comment: import skimage
from skimage import data
camera=data.camera()
these are my lines of code. But it is showing error continuously. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling as well.

Comment: Try formatting the code for readability.

Comment: Use file explorer to verify there is a file named: `camera.png` in folder `C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\skimage\data`.

Comment: yes there is the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have almost a similar problem. The solution for me is to install and upgrade the `scikit-image` module:

```
pip install -U scikit-image
```